# Как избавиться от большого количества COM портов?

Tags: bluetooth, com-port

Имеется bluetooth модуль hc-05, и bluetooth донгла с известного китайского сайта. При сопряжении в диспетчере устройств появляется целая куча COM портов. При этом реально рабочий из них - один (подключается и данные передаются). Как исправить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема-то? работает? работает... не глючит? нет... ну и не надо его трогать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что не все порты работают, из всех - putty и Terminal 1.9 подключатся только к одному, и приходится перебирать весь этот список - чтобы найти один ликвидный..

Comment: *приходится перебирать весь этот список - чтобы найти один* Диспетчер устройств - Вид - Устройства по подключению, и смотри, к какому порту подключается нужное оборудование. Опять же никто не мешает один раз там же отключить все "ненужные" порты (проблемы в будущем с подключением другого оборудования - за свой счёт).

Comment: Странно, у меня в устройствах по подключению вообще нет com портов. Но идею я понял, спасибо за ответ. Просто мне не нравится сам факт такого положения вещей. Хотелось понять причину по которой так происходит и по возможности её исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что таким образом они зарезервировали под каждое устройство отдельный COM port. Поэтому будьте внимательны выключая определённые порты

Список COM портов

```
comdisable /list
```

Отключить 17-й порт

```
comdisable /disable com17
```

Включить 17-й порт

```
comdisable /enable com17
```